# Big Commerce - Custom Price Retrieval

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm looking at using Big Commerce.

Is it possible through customizations that I can programmatically pull a price via a web service based on who the user is?

User logs into my store; when they search, for each product the price (and some other information) is being populated by a web service call. Same goes for the product page, cart, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this would be possible, although the implementation may vary depending on the size of your catalog/number of individual users who need pricing unique to them.

One option would be to call your web service for pricing and send those prices to the storefront for a specific customer (or group of customers) using the Price Lists API:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/catalog/pricelists-api

Another possibility would be to listen for the ID of the logged in customer, and based on that ID, update the prices of the products in the cart using the Cart API:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/cart-checkout/server-server-cart-api

Comment: Links are outdated.

Comment: Thanks @redrum. Updated.